# Is this a proof for the rational distance problem of a unit square?

Tags: combinatorial-number-theory

I found this 2015 research paper (http://unsolvedproblems.org/S75.pdf) that claims it has solved the rational distance problem of a unit square. When I look in other stackexchange and reddit threads, however, people say that it's yet unsolved. Is there an error in this paper?

Comment: Calling the document you linked a "research paper" is rather optimistic.

Comment: agreed but wanted to be polite